# Know property of table dtOptions

Tags: node.js, angular

How to know property of table dtOptions?

I do not understand what would be happening or what is missing, If I get to list and draw the table and IF it loads the data the only drawback is that I get unknown property as shown in the capture

at app.module.ts

```
import { DataTablesModule } from 'angular-datatables';
```

```js
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    DataTablesModule
  ],
```

In my user.component.ts

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {}; ....}
```

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUsers();
    this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType:'full_numbers',
      pageLength:10,
      processing:true,
      language:{
        url:'//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json'
      }
    }
  }
```

But in my HTML component it marks me as unknown property

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class AngularWayComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
  dtTrigger: Subject = new Subject();

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
```